# SDL 2 вывод fps

Tags: sdl, c++

Подскажите как вывести fps с помощью SDL 2? Может есть какой-нибудь туториал?

Читаю http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson07/index.php.

Проблема: У меня нет функции SDL_Flip.

Вывожу через `SDL_RenderCopy` и `SDL_RenderPresent`.

Можно конечно в текстуру запихать surface с текстом, но мне надо выводить fps. Неужели постоянно его пихать в текстуру?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам не давно искал ответ на этот же вопрос и вот нашел:

http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/24_calculating_frame_rate/index.php

Потом нашел порт их туторилов в SDL2 [здесь](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Загружать в текстуру тебе нужно 1 раз в секунду, всего лишь, а выводить на экран 60 раз в секунду.